# Can I convert blog entries to wiki articles for Leopard-to-Lion migration?

Tags: macos, server.app, file-conversion

We are migrating our Leopard server to Lion. We were using Group wikis and blogs in such a way that I didn't make much of a distinction, so it came as a shock to realize that Lion Server doesn't support group blogs. Hence, we need to convert the blog entries to wiki articles, which is fine. But, what is the least painful way to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct, 1-to-1 migration, I found [this link](http://www.jonsblog.org/2012/05/12/export-osx-wiki-server-to-csv/) which may be of help to at least export the data to CSV. Good luck